# My webpage wont work while I write this statement

Tags: php, sql

```
 <div style="margin-left:-7px ! important;">
 <?php
     $sql4 = "SELECT * FROM abc ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
     $query4 = $conn->query($sql4);
     $row4 = $query4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     $link4 = $row4['link_url'];
     $images4 = $row4['imagepath'];
     $immg4 = basename($images4);
     $imagee4 = "adverts"."/".$immg4;
     $rowc = $query4->rowCount(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     if ($rowc>=1){
        echo "
        <a href='$link4'; target='_blank'><img src='$imagee4';></a>";
     }
     else {
        echo "";
     }
?>
```

I want to run below script in else condition that mention above in echo part, but I don't  understand how to put this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   ( function() {
      if (window.CHITIKA === undefined) { window.CHITIKA = { 'units' : [] }; };
     var unit =  {
         "calltype"  : "async[2]",
         "publisher" : "seeknfameads",
         "width"     : 300, 
         "height"    :250, 
         "sid"       :"Chitika Default",
         "color_site_link" : "337ab7",
         "color_text" : "337ab7"
     };
     var placement_id = window.CHITIKA.units.length;
     window.CHITIKA.units.push(unit);
     document.write('<div id="chitikaAdBlock-' + placement_id + '"></div>');
 }());
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.chitika.net/getads.js" async>             </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this method : 
`

```
else { ?>
  <script>
   (function() {
     if (window.CHITIKA === undefined) {window.CHITIKA = {'units': []}};
     var unit = {"calltype":"async[2]","publisher":"seeknfameads","width":300,"height":250,"sid"     :"Chitika Default","color_site_link":"337ab7","color_text":"337ab7"};
     var placement_id = window.CHITIKA.units.length;
     window.CHITIKA.units.push(unit);
     document.write('<div id="chitikaAdBlock-' + placement_id + '"></div>');
     }());
     </script>
     <script src="//cdn.chitika.net/getads.js" async></script>
 <?php } ?>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

```
else{
   $output = <<< 'EOT'
      <script type="text/javascript">
      ( function () (...paste everything you want to output here...
EOT;

   //just echo the output
   echo $output;
}
```

Note that the closing `EOT;` must be by itself on a line, with no space before or after it

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use js between php then try this

```
<div style="margin-left:-7px ! important;">
 <?php
        $sql4 = "SELECT * FROM abc ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
        $query4 = $conn->query($sql4);
        $row4 = $query4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $link4 = $row4['link_url'];
        $images4 = $row4['imagepath'];
        $immg4 = basename($images4);
        $imagee4 = "adverts"."/".$immg4;
        $rowc = $query4->rowCount(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($rowc>=1){
        echo "
        <a href='$link4'; target='_blank'><img src='$imagee4';></a>";
        }
        else { ?>
              <script type="text/javascript">
              ( function() {
              if (window.CHITIKA === undefined) { window.CHITIKA = { 'units' : [] }; };
             var unit =  {"calltype":"async[2]","publisher":"seeknfameads","width":300,"height":250,"sid"     :"Chitika Default","color_site_link":"337ab7","color_text":"337ab7"};
             var placement_id = window.CHITIKA.units.length;
             window.CHITIKA.units.push(unit);
             document.write('<div id="chitikaAdBlock-' + placement_id + '"></div>');
    <?php   }
    ?>
```

Comment: if its works then accept my answer and close this question :)

Comment: when i upload image than it not fit in the div :(  <a href='$link4'; target='_blank'><img src='$imagee4';></a>"; in this statement.

Comment: you add this line with php example echo '<a href="">'; like this or not ?

Comment: echo "<a href='$link4'; target='_blank'><img src='$imagee4';></a> ";  i write this line. how to change width and height of coming image from database in this? as it fit in div width is 300 and height is 250

Comment: try this echo "<a href='".$link4."'; target='_blank'><img src='".$imagee4."';></a> "; and for height you can use 
echo "<a href='".$link4."'; height='".$yourHeightVariable.
"' target='_blank'><img src='".$imagee4."';></a> ";

Comment: how to write fix height expect .$yourHeightVariable. lets suppose 300 px

Comment: then you have to write "<a href='".$link4."'; height='300px' target='_blank'><img src='".$imagee4."';></a> ";

Comment: and also don't forget to remove semicolumn(;) after href ex - "<a href='".$link4."' height='300px' target='_blank'><img src='".$imagee4."';></a> ";

Comment: i applied this line. but height remain same. not working :(

Comment: then you can assign a class to your img 
<a href='".$link4."' class='imgcls' target='_blank'><img src='".$imagee4."';></a> ";
and class style should be <style> .imgcls { height:300px!important; }

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div style="margin-left:-7px ! important;">
 <?php
    $sql4 = "SELECT * FROM abc ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $query4 = $conn->query($sql4);
    $row4 = $query4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $link4 = $row4['link_url'];
    $images4 = $row4['imagepath'];
    $immg4 = basename($images4);
    $imagee4 = "adverts"."/".$immg4;
    $rowc = $query4->rowCount(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($rowc>=1){
    echo "
    <a href='$link4'; target='_blank'><img src='$imagee4';></a>";
    }
    else { ?>
          <script type="text/javascript">
          ( function() {
          if (window.CHITIKA === undefined) { window.CHITIKA = { 'units' : [] }; };
         var unit =  {"calltype":"async[2]","publisher":"seeknfameads","width":300,"height":250,"sid"     :"Chitika Default","color_site_link":"337ab7","color_text":"337ab7"};
         var placement_id = window.CHITIKA.units.length;
         window.CHITIKA.units.push(unit);
         document.write('<div id="chitikaAdBlock-' + placement_id + '"></div>');
<?php   }
?>
```

this is the answer by #shubham thanks